# Display the functionality of the script with argparse

Tags: python, argparse

when I invoke my script with -h I want it to print a message saying "This script does so and so"

What I mean is when I do

```
$myscript --help
```

It should show

```
This script is used to fire monkeys and hire donkeys.

usage -- ....
```

Comment: I can pass a string to ArgumentParser but it prints that message after "usage"

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add more information. Could you add an example of what you see now and how you would like it to look instead? Your question is very unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question:

I needed to use

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="This script ... "
```

Comment: and if you want some text after the options list, use `epilog="But wait, there's more"` in the same function you set `description=`

Answer (score 0):

simply add help="my help message" to each argument.
http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#add-help